# How do I pass guid in parameterised query?

Tags: c#, guid, parameterized-query

My current best code is:

```
string delNonQuery = "DELETE FROM " + Settings.DataSource + " WHERE @keycolumn=@keyuid";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delNonQuery,readerConn);
SqlParameter kc = new SqlParameter("keycolumn", SqlDbType.VarChar);
SqlParameter key = new SqlParameter("keyuid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(kc).Value = Settings.KeyColumn;
cmd.Parameters.Add(key).Value = Page.Request["key"].ToString().Trim();

readerConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
readerConn.Close();
```

This executes but affects a whopping zero rows. If I change the SqlDbType on keyuid to UniqueIdentifier it just ends up with me getting a dozen variations on "failed to convert character string into uniqueidentifier". I have to use a parameterized query for data cleanliness, I'm just really stuck as to how...

Comment: Thank you all for your concern over SQL Injection. I should point out that the only person who could SQL inject this is the person using the server side control that it comes from. As this would essentially entail them SQL injecting a datsource they presumably have admin rights to I figured it was minimal. The keyid, on the other hand... which is why it's parameterized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify a parameter for a column name - you need to concatenate it the same way you do for the table name.

This:

```
"DELETE FROM " + Settings.DataSource + " WHERE @keycolumn=@keyuid"
```

Should change to:

```
"DELETE FROM " + Settings.DataSource + " WHERE " + Settings.KeyColumn + " =@keyuid"
```

Though I would probably write it as:

```
string delNonQuery = string.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1} = @keyuid", 
                                   Settings.DataSource, 
                                   Settings.KeyColumn);
```

---

For completeness sake, I will mention that this is open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You need to make sure your `Settings` values are clean.

Comment: Yup, that was it. What is the benefit of using string.Format?

Comment: @One Monkey - Readability and ease of maintenance.

Comment: I don't want to be a pain but I'm sorry I don't get it. Readability is moot, anyone could probably understand the original but the curly braces one requires some domain knowledge, it does make reading the query a little smoother if you understand the convention though. The ease of maintenance thing I really don't understand how is one easier to maintain than the other? I'm not trying to be annoying I just genuinely don't get it.

Comment: @One Monkey - When you need to add a parameter or remove one, for example. I personally find format strings to be more readable than long concatenated strings.

Comment: Okay, I get it. This example is probably not the best as it's kind of done, but I have definitely encountered situations where it's got a bit out of control.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can parameterise the column name ("keycolumn")

Try this:

```
string delNonQuery = string.Format("DELETE FROM " + Settings.DataSource + " WHERE {0}=@keyuid", Settings.KeyColumn);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delNonQuery,readerConn);
SqlParameter key = new SqlParameter("keyuid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(key).Value = Page.Request["key"].ToString().Trim();

readerConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
readerConn.Close();
```

Usual warnings apply regarding concatanating strings to build SQL; this is likely a security risk.

The best method might be to encapsulate your SQL in a stored procedure, pass the column name and value as parameters and then execute using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for that. Works perfectly. What benefit does string.Format bring to this?

Comment: Passing the guid string value as a "SqlDbType.NVarChar" rather than a "SqlDbType.UniqueItentifier" worked for me too. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to GUID:

Relevant Lines:

```
SqlParameter key = new SqlParameter("keyuid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
...
cmd.Parameters.Add(key).Value = new Guid(Page.Request["key"].ToString().Trim());
```

Which only solves the GUID/UniqueIdentifer issue

Comment: I did that. It fails the conversion.